# Formatting a fraction as a mixed number

Tags: output-formatting, number-representation

Is there a command that will take a rational number and rewrite it in a mixed-number-like form?  That is, I'd like to apply a command to something like `10/7` and get the result `1 + 3/7` (or `3/7 + 1` would be fine, too).  With polynomial division, the `Apart[]` command does the trick pretty well, but I haven't been able to find anything comparable for numbers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a definition for `mixedForm` that works for all cases, i.e. proper and improper fractions and integers.

```
Clear[mixedForm]
mixedForm[Rational[x_, y_]] := 
    If[Abs@x > y, HoldForm[#1 + #2/y], x/y] & @@ (Sign@x QuotientRemainder[Abs@x, y])
mixedForm[x_Integer] := x
```

Some examples:

```
mixedForm /@ {2, 4/5, 10/3, -3/4, -5/2}
Out[1]= {2, 4/5, 3 + 1/3, -3/4, -2 - 1/2}
```

Compare with Eli's, which produces `0`s if the number is an integer or a proper fraction

```
ImproperForm /@ {2, 4/5, 10/3, -3/4, -5/2}
Out[2]= {2 + 0, 0 + 4/5, 3 + 1/3, -1 + 1/4, -3 + 1/2}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think yours is better.

Comment: Nice... But, if -3/4 is -3/4, shouldn't -5/2 be -2-1/2?

Comment: @Rojo This no longer makes problems if we use  `FractionalPart` and `IntegerPart` instead of `QuotientRemainder`. Look at my approach.

Comment: @Rojo Thanks for catching that. This is easily fixed — see edit :)

Comment: There goes your +1

Comment: Maybe you can replace `HoldForm[]` with `Defer[]`, so the output is usable as input when copied and pasted.

Answer (score 8):

Using the function from the notebook [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MixedFraction.html):

```
ImproperForm[x_] := 
 Function[{z, y}, HoldForm[z + y], {HoldAll}] @@ {Floor[x],x - Floor[x]}
```

Usage:

```
In[12]:= ImproperForm[10/7]
Out[12]= 1+3/7
```

Answer (score 8):

Another solution based on `FractionalPart` and `IntegerPart` would be :

```
Fraction[x_Rational]:= 
    Function[{z, y}, If[z!=0, HoldForm[z + y], HoldForm[y]],    
                     {HoldAll}] @@ {IntegerPart[x], FractionalPart[x]}

Fraction[x_Integer] := x
```

This approach produces slightly different results than R.M.'s solution :

```
Fraction /@ {2, 4/5, 10/3, -3/4, -5/2}
```

> ```
> {2, 4/5, 3 + 1/3, -3/4, -2 -1/2 }
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an attempt to implement both formatting for entire expressions and basic arithmetic.

EDIT: fixed according to Artes' solution.

```
ClearAll[mixedForm]    
Format[mixedForm[x : Except[_Rational]]] := x /. q_Rational :> mixedForm[q]    
Format[mixedForm[q_Rational]] ^:= Interpretation[
   If[Abs[q] < 1, q, HoldForm[# + #2] & @@ {IntegerPart@q, FractionalPart@q}],
   q
 ]

mixedForm[q_] + (mixedForm[x_] | x_) ^:= mixedForm[q + x]
mixedForm[q_] * (mixedForm[x_] | x_) ^:= mixedForm[q * x]
mixedForm[q_] ^ (mixedForm[x_] | x_) ^:= mixedForm[q ^ x]
```

Now:

```
ff[2, 4/5, 10/3, gg[-3/4, -5/2]] // mixedForm
(* Out[1]= ff[2, 4/5, 3 + 1/3, gg[-(3/4), -2 - 1/2]] *)

x = mixedForm[8/3];
y = mixedForm[9/5];    
x + y
(* Out[2]= 4 + 7/15 *)

x + 1/2
(* Out[3]= 3 + 1/6 *)
```

Comment: I knew you wouldn't have just given up

Comment: @Rojo I'm trying to take [my own advice](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277/121).  (Again to the OP, I am not saying this is a low quality question, only that I am trying to respond with more than the most basic answer.)

Comment: What about something like `mixedForm /: h_[bef___, mixedForm[stuff_], aft___] := 
 h[bef, stuff, aft]` for the arithmetic?

Comment: @Rojo have you tried that?

Answer (score 5):

This should work with any real, rationalizing it (so, it becomes an approximate result)... 
The integer part of a negative number is considered the floor of the number. I'm not sure what's desired in those cases...

```
ClearAll[MixedForm];

Format[MixedForm[r_?NumericQ]] := Module[{rat = 
  If[Element[r, Rationals], r,Rationalize[N@r, 0]], x, y},
   {x, y} = Through@{Numerator, Denominator}[rat];
   With[{num = x, den = y},
    With[{quot = Quotient[num, den], rem = Mod[num, den]},
     Defer[quot] + Defer[rem/den] /. Defer[_?PossibleZeroQ] -> 0]]];

MixedForm /: (h_Symbol /; MemberQ[Attributes[h], NumericFunction])[
   bef___, MixedForm[stuff_], aft___] := MixedForm@h[bef, stuff, aft];

SetAttributes[MixedForm, {Listable, Flat}];

Unprotect[$OutputForms];
AppendTo[$OutputForms, MixedForm];
Protect[$OutputForms];
```

Ok, first, we test it

```
MixedForm /@ {2, 4/5, 10/3, -3/4, -5/2}

{2, 4/5, 3 + 1/3, -1 + 1/4, -3 + 1/2}
```

Works as expected, if you expected the integer part to be the floor (which I don't think it's the most natural thing but I'm not sure)

We see that the function can also take machine precision numbers

```
MixedForm /@ {2.`, 0.8`, 3.333333333333333`, -0.75`, -2.5`}
```

gives the same result.

For consistency with built-ins, the retuned cell has the label with `//MixedForm` prepended. Unlike some of the other options based on `HoldForm`, you can copy the result and do arithmetics with it... You can also do some arithmetics with the returned values

```
{2, 4/5, 10/3, -3/4, -5/2} // MixedForm

{2, 4/5, 3 + 1/3, -1 + 1/4, -3 + 1/2}



% + 9

{11, 9 + 4/5, 12 + 1/3, 8 + 1/4, 6 + 1/2}
```

**EDIT**

Added the `Listable` and `Flat` attribute and changed the previous definition to only match numeric values. Now we don't need to map it

```
{2, 4/5, 10/3, -3/4, -5/2} // MixedForm
```

returns what's expected... But we lose the label in these cases

Comment: Could you give some examples of use and what you see as the strengths of this method?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, sorry, wrong edit, now

Comment: This has the same error that you pointed out in mine ;) Also, you probably don't want to make the claim — _"This should work with any real, rationalizing it..."_. I'd like to see a rationalized result for `MixedForm[Sqrt[2]]` :D Nevertheless, I voted for it :)

Comment: Hehe, thanks for pointing out the `Sqrt[2]`, the idea was for it to be approximate in those cases so I should change it to `Rationalize[N@r, 0]` for non rationals. Actually I got lost multitasking and I don't like my function much, I'd redo it... But it doesn't have that inconsistency I pointed out in yours, it just consistently chooses perhaps the "wrong" option, hehe. Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 3):

I am using this function to make up problems for middle schoolers.  They are used to writing mixed numbers without the sign between the integer part and fraction parts.

This version prints mixed numbers as middle schoolers expect them:

```
mF[Rational[x_, y_]] := 
  If[Abs@x > y, Sign@x HoldForm[#1] HoldForm[#2/y], x/y] & @@ (Abs@QuotientRemainder[x, y]);
mF[x_Integer] := x;
```

Answer (score 2):

For some time I've used a variation of the function *mixRational*, so named because the output produced are called "mixed numbers."
[EDIT: updated to handle negative arguments; several answers above fail. I prefer no sign to appear between the integer and fractional parts]

```
ClearAll[mixRational];
SetAttributes[mixRational, Listable];
mixRational[x_] := 
  If[Head[x] =!= Rational, x, 
   With[{i = IntegerPart[x]}, 
    If[i == 0, x, Row[{i, Abs[FractionalPart[x - i]]}]]]];
mixRational[{5/2, -5/2, 10/3 + 10/3, 7, 3.3, Pi, foo}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another one:

```
MixedNumberForm[expr_] := 
 Interpretation[expr /. r_Rational :> 
   Which[
     IntegerPart[r] == 0, r,
     FractionalPart[r] == 0, r,
     True,
     Row[{IntegerPart[r], FractionalPart[Abs[r]]}]
   ],
   expr]
```

The row box looks nice, keeps the code simple.

```
  {2, 4/5, 10/3, -3/4, -5/2} // MixedNumberForm

  Out[2]= {2, 4/5, 3 1/3, -3/4, -2 1/2}
```

Applying the MixedNumberForm to the whole expression  works after TableForm or Grid or whatever else you might be using.

Because it's an Interpretation, you can paste the whole expression and all of the mixed numbers will revert to rationals.